# Operator Overloading in C++ (small error)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, operator-overloading, operators

I have a small error with operator overloading that's been bugging me.

I've got a class:

```
class Fraction{

private:

//Variables

    int numerator;
    int denominator;

//Constructor



public:

//Methods

    Fraction();
    Fraction(int, int);
};
```

I also have this operator overloading function:

```
Fraction& operator+=(const Fraction& f);
```

It seems like it would build fine to me, but the compiler is giving me this error message:

```
In file included from Fraction.cpp:3:
./Fraction.h:31:11: error: overloaded 'operator+=' must be a binary operator
      (has 1 parameter)
Fraction& operator+=(const Fraction& f);
          ^
1 error generated.
```

Every single example of += I've seen so far is identical to what I'm doing as far, from what I can tell. If someone could point out my stupidity, that would be great!

Comment: put this function inside the Fraction class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either declare the operator as a member function of the class or if it is a non-class function then it shall have two parameters

For example

**1 member function**

```
class Fraction
{

private:

//Variables

    int numerator;
    int denominator;

//Constructor



public:

//Methods

    Fraction();
    Fraction(int, int);
    Fraction& operator +=( const Fraction &rhs );
};
```

**2. non-member function**

```
class Fraction
{

private:

//Variables

    int numerator;
    int denominator;

//Constructor



public:

//Methods

    Fraction();
    Fraction(int, int);
    friend Fraction& operator +=( Fraction &lhs, const Fraction &rhs );
};

Fraction& operator +=( Fraction &lhs, const Fraction &rhs ) { /* some code */ }
```

Take into account that then the operator is a non-class function you may not use **this**
Also the non-class operator should be a friend function of the class if there is no public access to corresponding data members through getters and setters.

Comment: Thank you very much for the in depth answer. I thought as much. Though I'm now getting linking errors, at least I now know that i'm on the right track. Thanks to all and cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should put

```
Fraction& operator+=(const Fraction& f);
```

declaration inside class if it has to be binary operation. Alternatively you can declare this operator in global namespace taking two instances of `Fraction`, but make it friend of this class (as it needs access to private data) by declaring friendship in `Fraction` through:

```
friend Fraction& operator+=( Fraction& l, const Fraction& r);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a free function, it should have 2 parameters (binary operator).
Declare it inside the `Fraction` class instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you overload the operator as a non-member function you need to write it like this

```
Fraction& operator+=(const Fraction& lhs, const Fraction& rhs);
```

Answer (score 0):

This errors occurs when your overloaded operator is outside your class as global.

You should try give declaration of this operator into your class as:

```
Fraction& operator+=(const Fraction& f);
```

You can leave as you did but then you must change operator to this:

```
Fraction& operator+=(const Fraction& f, const Fraction& g);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209434/why-does-my-operator-overloading-handle-left-versus-right-objects/22209742#22209742) you can find some more information in my post